# If the canonical embedding is an isomorphism then U is a principal ultrafilter

Tags: first-order-logic

My question is the reciprocal of this one: [Show that if U is a principal ultrafilter then the canonical inmersion is an isomorphism between $\mathcal A$ and $Ult_{U}\mathcal A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605091/show-that-if-u-is-a-principal-ultrafilter-then-the-canonical-inmersion-is-an-iso)

I also assume that $M$ is infinite. By the very nature of the canonical embedding and Los theorem, we have an elementary embedding of $M$ in $M^I/U$. I wish to prove that, if $j:I \to M$ (the canonical embedding) is onto then the ultrafilter is principal.

I have already proven the case $|I| \leq |M|$. In this case I manufacture a injective  function and look at the element in $M$ that goes to this element with the canonical embedding.

But I can't conclude the principalness of $U$ if the cardinality of $I$ is bigger then the cardinality of $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ZFC is consistent, it is also consistent that if $U$ is non-principal, and $M$ is infiniite, then  the canonical embedding is proper.

But under suitable large cardinal axioms, there exists a set $I$, and a non-principal ultrafilter $U$ on $I$, such that $U$ is countably complete, that is, the countable intersection of sets in $U$ is in $U$. For such an ultrafilter, and countably infinite $M$, the natural embedding of $M$ in $M^I/U$ is an isomorphism.  For more information, please search under $\kappa$-complete ultrafilters and measurable cardinals.

Comment: That was very enlightening. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. Pretty good, asking a question which cannot be settled within ZFC!  This was historically the first "large cardinal" axiom, and predated ultrafilters and ultrapowers.

Comment: I worked out the details and all I needed was a non-principal $\aleph_1$-complete ultrafilter $U$ in some set $I$ and then I took a structure with cardinality $\aleph_0$ and it was very easy showing that the canonical embedding was indeed a isomorphism. Do we really need large cardinals axioms for this? I was thinking about using real compact space or something alike.

Comment: Yes, we really do need a measurable cardinal, and such a cardinal is strongly inaccessible, and more.  In particular $V=L$ implies there aren't any.